# Append a post request inside of a div

Tags: php, html

I want to append preformatted HTML inside of a div sent to my PHP file. It needs to save.
Example:

```
<div id="posts">
   <!-insert here-->
</div>
```

and I send a post request containing

```
<article id="x">
    <h1>x</h1>
    <p>y</p>
</article>
```

the article id matches the contents of h1. This is compiled before sending post request. I wrote a compiler. After appending I want it to look like

```
<div id="posts">
   <!-insert here-->
   <article id="x">
     <h1>x</h1>
     <p>y</p>
   </article>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use JSON?

Comment: let's see what's your code so far.

Comment: @Nordenheim My hosting service doesn't support json parsing.

Comment: @Federkun code for what

Comment: Your question is too broad. From where the _preformatted HTML_ comes from? how do you send `<article id="x"><h1>x</h1><p>y</p></article>` via `post request` and to where do you send this request? You have selected `php` in your tags but there is not a single line of a `php` code shared in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 <div id="posts">
    <?php echo '
    <article id=\"x\">
    <h1>x</h1>
    <p>y</p>
    </article>'
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It needs to append. So add a new article after an old one. And it needs to save @phabi0

Comment: `<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
// The new person to add to the file
$article = "<article id=\"x\">\n
    <h1>x</h1>\n
    <p>y</p>\n
    </article>\n";
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $article, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>`

Comment: in essence you could append it to a file, or add it to a database with the latter being the preferred method.